# mdframed: Put a line below the frame title and give it a shaded background

Tags: framed, mdframed

I like to use `mdframed` to make a framed environment with an optional title. The title has to be in its own box with a gray background, like this:
[image: example]

I hope that this is possible.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{Frame}[with Title]
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text
\begin{Frame}% no Title
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text
\end{document}
```

I like to use `mdframed` instead of the package and hack to make the picture above because it is more flexible :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

The version 1.2 of mdframed has new possibilities for setting the frame title. Based of your request you can simple use the option `frametitlerule=true` and `frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20`.
The current version is available at [github](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{Frame}[with Title]
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text
\begin{Frame}% no Title
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

<sub>By using `tikz` to modify the header here one suggestion.</sub>

<sub>You have to modify the command `\mdframetitleenv` to influence the output. The package itself controls whether the frame title is empty or not.</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\makeatletter
%ORIGINAL
%\providecommand*\mdframedtitleenv[1]{%
%  \@afterindentfalse
%   {\parindent \z@
%         \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}%
%         \mdraggedtitle\nobreak\mdf@frametitlefont#1\relax%
%    \par}%
%  \@afterheading}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, %
                    fill=gray!20,%
                    line width=\mdf@middlelinewidth@length,
                    rectangle,
                    inner sep=0pt,
                    inner ysep=0.333em,
                    minimum height=1cm,
                    text width = \linewidth
                                 +\mdf@innerleftmargin@length
                                 +\mdf@innerrightmargin@length
                                 +\mdf@linewidth@length,
                    align=left,
                    ]
\renewcommand*{\mdframedtitleenv}[1]{%
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\mdf@innertopmargin@length-\mdf@linewidth@length\relax}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\hspace*{\dimexpr-\mdf@innerleftmargin@length-\mdf@linewidth@length\relax}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node [mybox]{\hspace*{\mdf@innerrightmargin@length}%
   \parbox{\linewidth}{\mdf@frametitlefont#1\relax}};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\par
\@afterheading
}%
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{Frame}[with Title]
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text

\begin{Frame}[with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title with Title]
    Text
\end{Frame}

Text
\begin{Frame}% no Title
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :-) I don’t need it at the moment i guess but do you have an idea how to make this work with titles longer than one line?

Comment: PS: Is there a common way to prevent a pagebreak right after the frame title?

Comment: Thank you, seems to work now. I tried `needspace` befor but it doesn’t seem to work with `2\baselineskip` only with fix values

Comment: No I didn’t. I’ll send an e-mail to your address given in the manual.

Comment: @Tobi: Please see my edit

Comment: Thanks you. Sounds interesting but according to “Nevr touch a running system” I’ll keep the old solution this time and keep the new one in mind for future projects (I guess the new version will be available on CTAN soon, right?). Are you using the same solution as last time but internally or is it completely new (improved?) code?

Comment: @Tobi: I have many changes. I hope everything works as usual I had a beta test phase with some response. At the moment I expand the examples and then I will upload to CTAN. https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/c86a416bc362e69e?hl=de#