# mdthereom shared counters, cleverref, and nested theorems

Tags: numbering, environments, counters, mdframed

I am having trouble trying to set up mdframed so that

1. it is compatible with cleverref
2. all mdframed boxes share the same counter
3. does not break when mdframed environments are nested

Demo file. Ideally we should see

- Lemma 1.1: main lemma
- Note 1.2: calculations
- Lemma 1.3: calculation 1
- Lemma 1.4: calculation 2
- Remark 1.5: rmk 1

Here is my original preamble file, which accomplishes 1) and 3). But we have Lemma 1.1, Note 1.1, Lemma 1.2, Lemma 1.3. Remark 1.1 Because the counters are separate for each `\mdtheorem`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor,mdframed,hyperref,cleveref}

%Headers and Sections

% Colors

\definecolor{tab-blue}{rgb}{0.341,0.471,0.643}
\definecolor{tab-orange}{rgb}{0.894,0.580,0.267}

%%%
%Counters
\newcounter{thechapter}
%%%
% Define fChapter
%for putting chapter numbers after the title


% Chapters
\newcommand{\fchapter}[1]%
{%
    \phantomsection\chapter*{Chapter #1}%
    \stepcounter{thechapter}
    \newpage% Chapter Number
} 

% Copy the same style but modify the colour only
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-blue!10
}

\mdfdefinestyle{remarkstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-blue!5,
}

\mdfdefinestyle{notestyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-orange!5,
}

\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{lemma}{Lemma}[thechapter]
\mdtheorem[style=remarkstyle]{remark}{Remark}[thechapter]
\mdtheorem[style=notestyle]{note}{Note}[thechapter]

% Here we manage Clever Headers
\crefname{lemma}{lem.}{lems.}
\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\crefname{note}{note}{notes}
\Crefname{note}{Note}{Notes}

\begin{document}
\fchapter{1: main result}
\begin{lemma}[main lemma]\label{lem:main}
1234556
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
    123
\begin{note}[calculations]
\begin{lemma}[calculation 1]\label{lem:calc 1}
calc 1 here
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
calc 1 proof
\end{proof}
\begin{lemma}[calculation 2]\label{lem:calc 2}
calc 2 here
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
calc 2 proof
\end{proof}
\begin{remark}[rmk 1]\label{rmk: rmk 1}
rmk 
\end{remark}
\end{note}

\end{proof}

Cleveref tests: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item main lemma \cref{lem:main}
    \item note calculations: \cref{note:calculations}
    \item lemma calc 1: \cref{lem:calc 1}
    \item lemma calc 2: \cref{lem:calc 2}
    \item rmk 1 1: \cref{rmk: rmk 1}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Taking inspiration from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42293/numbered-mdframed-environment-but-without-using-theorem-hacks), and using a new counter, `boxcounter`, I have replaced the three `\mdtheorem` lines within the previous document. We now have a shared counter, but we broke cleveref, (which shows ??? when trying to reference the environments). This is because `\cref` is trying to reference the boxcounter instead of the environment itself.

Nested environments are also broken, with repeated numbers (Note 1.5 should be Note 1.2), as compiling the document gives

Lemma 1.1, Note 1.5, Lemma 1.3, Lemma 1.4, Remark 1.5.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor,mdframed,hyperref,cleveref}
% Colors
\definecolor{tab-blue}{rgb}{0.341,0.471,0.643}
\definecolor{tab-orange}{rgb}{0.894,0.580,0.267}

%%%
%Counters
\newcounter{thechapter}

% Chapters
\newcommand{\fchapter}[1]%
{%
    \phantomsection\chapter*{Chapter #1}%
    \stepcounter{thechapter}
    \newpage% Chapter Number
} 

% Copy the same style but modify the colour only
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-blue!10
}

\mdfdefinestyle{remarkstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-blue!5,
}

\mdfdefinestyle{notestyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-orange!5,
}

\newcounter{boxcounter}[thechapter]
\renewcommand{\theboxcounter}{\arabic{thechapter}.\arabic{boxcounter}}

\newenvironment{lemma}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{boxcounter}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={Lemma \theboxcounter\ #1},
        style=theoremstyle
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{note}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{boxcounter}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={Note \theboxcounter\ #1},
        style=notestyle
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{remark}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{boxcounter}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={Remark \theboxcounter\ #1},
        style=remarkstyle
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

% Here we manage Clever Headers
\crefname{lemma}{lem.}{lems.}
\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\crefname{note}{note}{notes}
\Crefname{note}{Note}{Notes}

\begin{document}
\fchapter{1: main result}
\begin{lemma}[main lemma]\label{lem:main}
1234556
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
    123
\begin{note}[calculations]\label{note:calculations}
\begin{lemma}[calculation 1]\label{lem:calc 1}
calc 1 here
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
calc 1 proof
\end{proof}
\begin{lemma}[calculation 2]\label{lem:calc 2}
calc 2 here
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
calc 2 proof
\end{proof}
\begin{remark}[rmk 1]\label{rmk: rmk 1}
rmk 
\end{remark}
\end{note}

\end{proof}

Cleveref tests: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item main lemma \cref{lem:main}
    \item note calculations: \cref{note:calculations}
    \item lemma calc 1: \cref{lem:calc 1}
    \item lemma calc 2: \cref{lem:calc 2}
    \item rmk 1 1: \cref{rmk: rmk 1}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code snippets, and not in multiple parts too. It is a lot easier for other people to answer your question is you post a COMPLETE minimum example code that you wish to ask about. As it stands if I copy your "skeleton code" in the first code display, and add you "preamble code" from the second display, the tex file will **not** compile due to missing `\usepackage` declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post compileable MWE, the answer below are not directly tailored to your needs, but only serves to illustrate the principle. The reason that your third displayed code block doesn't work is that you are using the same counter for the three environments. Cleveref uses the counter name to tell apart the various environments.

The solution to this (which is internally used by `cleveref` for handling theorem environments sharing the same counter created by `amsthm` which has the same problem), is to create a duplicate slave counter.

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{mastercounter}
\newcounter{envAcount}
\newcounter{envBcount}
\makeatletter
\let\c@envAcount\c@mastercounter
\let\c@envBcount\c@mastercounter
\makeatother

\newenvironment{envA}{\refstepcounter{envAcount}\textbf{First Environment \theenvAcount}\par}{}
\newenvironment{envB}{\refstepcounter{envBcount}\textbf{Second Enviornment \theenvBcount}\par}{}

\Crefname{envAcount}{First}{First}
\Crefname{envBcount}{Second}{Second}

\begin{document}

\begin{envA}\label{envAtest}
        Test
\end{envA}

\begin{envB}\label{envBtest}
        Another test
\end{envB}

\Cref{envAtest} and \Cref{envBtest}

\end{document}
```

1. this code creates three counters: `mastercounter`, `envAcount`, and `envBcount`.
2. the lines between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` make `envAcount` and `envBcount` internally the same counter as `mastercounter`, so increasing one increase all three<sup>*</sup>.
3. Then we define new environments `envA` and `envB`; note that in each environment you `\refstepcounter` either `envAcount` or `envBcount` as appropriate. This is important as the counter name is recorded in the `.aux` file when you `\label` the environment.
4. Note that we define the `\Crefname` using the *names of the counter*, not the names of the environment using the counter.

The code above yields the following output
[image]

You can now incorporate the trick yourself in your full document using `mdframed` to define your environments.

<sup>*</sup> An alternative to doing this by hand is to use a package like [aliascnt](https://ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt?lang=en).

---

Now that you've added a MWE, here's a version adapted to your MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor,mdframed,hyperref,cleveref}
% Colors
\definecolor{tab-blue}{rgb}{0.341,0.471,0.643}
\definecolor{tab-orange}{rgb}{0.894,0.580,0.267}

%%%
%Counters
\newcounter{thechapter}

% Chapters
\newcommand{\fchapter}[1]%
{%
    \phantomsection\chapter*{Chapter #1}%
    \stepcounter{thechapter}
    \newpage% Chapter Number
} 

% Copy the same style but modify the colour only
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-blue!10
}

\mdfdefinestyle{remarkstyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-blue!5,
}

\mdfdefinestyle{notestyle}{%
    backgroundcolor=tab-orange!5,
}

\newcounter{boxcounter}[thechapter]
\renewcommand{\theboxcounter}{\arabic{thechapter}.\arabic{boxcounter}}
\newcounter{lemma}
\newcounter{note}
\newcounter{remark}
\makeatletter
\let\c@lemma\c@boxcounter
\let\c@note\c@boxcounter
\let\c@remark\c@boxcounter
\let\thelemma\theboxcounter
\let\thenote\theboxcounter
\let\theremark\theboxcounter
\makeatother


\newenvironment{lemma}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{lemma}
    \edef\x{Lemma \thelemma\ #1}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={\x},
        style=theoremstyle
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{note}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{note}
    \edef\x{Note \thenote\ #1}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={\x},
        style=notestyle
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{remark}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{remark}
    \edef\x{Remark \theremark\ #1}
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={\x},
        style=remarkstyle
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

% Here we manage Clever Headers
\crefname{lemma}{lem.}{lems.}
\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\crefname{note}{note}{notes}
\Crefname{note}{Note}{Notes}

\begin{document}
\fchapter{1: main result}
\begin{lemma}[main lemma]\label{lem:main}
1234556
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
    123
\begin{note}[calculations]\label{note:calculations}
\begin{lemma}[calculation 1]\label{lem:calc 1}
calc 1 here
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
calc 1 proof
\end{proof}
\begin{lemma}[calculation 2]\label{lem:calc 2}
calc 2 here
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
calc 2 proof
\end{proof}
\begin{remark}[rmk 1]\label{rmk: rmk 1}
rmk 
\end{remark}
\end{note}

\end{proof}

Cleveref tests: 
\begin{itemize}
    \item main lemma \cref{lem:main}
    \item note calculations: \cref{note:calculations}
    \item lemma calc 1: \cref{lem:calc 1}
    \item lemma calc 2: \cref{lem:calc 2}
    \item rmk 1 1: \cref{rmk: rmk 1}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which shows

[image]

A trick here is the line

```
\edef\x{Note \thenote\ #1}
```

to work around the issue where if you put `\thenote` into `frametitle={Note \thenote\ #1}`, by the time `mdframed` gets around to expanding it the value of `\thenote` has already been changed by the interior environments. This trick basically makes sure to store the current value of `\thenote` into `\x`, and with the magic of "variable scoping" when the interior environment exits the value of `\x` is restored to what was the case before entering the environments.