# Inconsistent horizontal width of mdframed with only display math content

Tags: spacing, mdframed

**Update 2012-03-09:** With an version of `mdframed` updated today, this is now fixed in the package and no longer requires the workaround provided below.

---

In [Excess vertical space in mdframed ending with display math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44131/excess-vertical-space-in-mdframed-ending-with-display-math-environment), I had wrapped the contents on `mdframed` within a `minipage` and had intended to file this as a separate question, as I believe that the `minipage` wrapper should not be necessary.  Without this wrapper, if the content contains **only** display math, the width is not the full `\linewidth`.

Here is a snippet of the output showing the inconsistent output for the case of display math in red. Note that the output is fine if the frame has a title, but without the frame the width is not consistent:

[image]

### Questions:

- Is there a `mdframed` setting to adjust this?
  If not, is there any better way to get the desired behavior other than using a `minipage`?
- Is this a bug with `mdframed`, or a feature?

### Note:

- The code below is adapted from [mdframed: Put a line below the frame title and give it a shaded background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32345/mdframed-put-a-line-below-the-frame-title-and-give-it-a-shaded-background).
- Uncommenting the `\begin{minipage}` and `\end{minipage}` produces what I believe is the correct result (to be consistent with the first two cases).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30
    ]%
    %\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%  this should not be necessary??
}{%
    %\end{minipage}%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}\noindent
Text
\begin{Frame}[with Title]
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text
\begin{Frame}% no Title
    Text
\end{Frame}
Text
\begin{Frame}[Einstein]
    \begin{align*}
        e & = mc^2
    \end{align*}
\end{Frame}
Text
\begin{Frame}\color{red}% no Title
    \begin{align*}
        e & = mc^2
    \end{align*}
\end{Frame}
Text
\begin{Frame}\color{red}% no Title
    \begin{align*}
        e  &= mc^2\\
        F  &= ma
    \end{align*}
\end{Frame}
Text
\begin{Frame}\color{red}% no Title
    \[
        e  = mc^2
    \]
\end{Frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `minipage` as that stops breaking the frame, which is, presumably the main point of the `mdframed` frame, Between the `tikz` and the German I'm not sure whether it's a bug or (like `minipage`) it is a feature. A standard LaTeX `minipage` will similarly ignore its requested length and just use the natural length of its content if its content is just vertical material. (This is documented as working if you put a tabbing in `minipage` but it is generally true. So I'd just force the width by putting a rule in:

```
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30
    ]%
    \hrule height0pt width\hsize\relax%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<FORCE WIDTH
    %\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%  this should not be necessary??
}{%
    %\end{minipage}%
    \end{mdframed}
}
```

Comment: The width is lost if the frame does break over a page, you could put the rule in again before the mdframe ends, but that still doesn't catch multiple page cases. mdframe.sty already inserts a similar rule in lots of places, but I think it needs a few more, can't spot where at present though.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Fixed in the new version.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel:Great. Once it is released, please post an answer here.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Do read also the rss feed of CTAN ;-). It works now. I think a small editing of your question is enough. Please test the new version.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: This is now confirmed fixed in the package. Have updated the question to reflect this. Thanks for the quick turnaround.